# What is the fastest way to send a file from client PC to a remote machine?

Tags: ssh, file-transfer, remote-access, remote-connection

I tried to use SSH and FTP to send the file, but it was really slow (of course it depends also to the connection quality, but I think that my connection can provide better performance with another alternative method). Is there any other method that possibly works better than SSH?

Comment: Why do you think anything would work better than these?

Comment: Since it is free

Comment: FTP and SSH are protocols, not programs. You can buy a SSH or FTP client if you believe it will be faster just because it costs you money.

Comment: These are of course protocols but they have different implementations on different client.

Comment: So the question becomes: Which free clients did you try? This is a bit of a shopping/subjective question now anyway.

Comment: For instance if I connect to server throughout nautilus file browser and copy any file via SSH connection, it sends the data in KB/sec however if I send it via scp command, it send in ~1.5 MB/sec so I need a way of keeping this 1.5 rate

Answer (score 1):

There are several options for you to use here.  The ones you have already tried will work.  here are a couple that I use and enjoy how easy they are to setup.

1. TeamViewer: This is a free remote control management program that runs on HTTP port 80 and has an embedded file transfer between the two hosts you are using.  You do not state how large the file is you are sending, but I have used this interface to send several GB files so I know it works.  The one drawback is you have to remain logged into the remote machine while the file is being sent.  [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com)
2. BTsync: This is a client that runs on both PC's, you can have a single folder that is monitored and the remote machine will automatically start to download whatever is put into that folder.  This is very useful when you want to walk away (keeping your machine on) or not have to remain logged into the remote machine.
   [BTsync](http://labs.bittorent.com/experiments/sync)